# How to finalize docker image/container .NET5/Visual Studio

Tags: c#, docker

I created a new API with VS-2019 and added docker support. On create this builds a new Docker Image & Container and runs it.

[image]

When I try to open the container through the Browser it doesn't work, which is expected since the container is attached to VS and that's not running. When I run the project in VS the container works fine.

My question is how do I publish/finalize that container and application. My goal is to be able to access the Container without the need to run Visual Studio.

When I run the `docker ps` command it does show that the ports are bound, even when VS is not running.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                    CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                   NAMES
82123f6d26ec   mareldockerfoodchain:dev   "C:\\remote_debugger\\…"   38 minutes ago   Up 36 minutes   0.0.0.0:13102->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:13101->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:13100->900/tcp   Marel.Docker.Foodchain
```

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 900
ENV APSNETCORE_URLS=https://*:900

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Marel.Docker.Foodchain/Marel.Docker.Foodchain.csproj", "Marel.Docker.Foodchain/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Marel.Docker.Foodchain/Marel.Docker.Foodchain.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Marel.Docker.Foodchain"
RUN dotnet build "Marel.Docker.Foodchain.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Marel.Docker.Foodchain.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Marel.Docker.Foodchain.dll"]
```

Comment: Wild guess: you're not opening the port when you use the image away from Visual Studio.

Comment: @Llama not sure how to do that. I mean should the port not be exposed as defined in the `Dockerfile`? Or do I have to expose it a second time? Which would be strange as the `docker ps` command brings up that the PORTS are bound even through VS is not running.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose FYI: _"The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. "_ - are you actually publishing the port or just exposing it?

Comment: Re your edit: so you're trying to access your API on https://localhost:13100/something, right?

Comment: @Llama yes I am